# How to send monitoring data of Apache Karaf Decanter to a remote JM Broker?

Tags: jms, apache-karaf

I'm using Apache Karaf for some projects and I would like to collect several monitoring data. I saw that it is possible through the Apache Karaf Decanter and I deployed a working solution with Elasticsearch as a data appender.

However, now I would like to send the same data collected through the several Decanter collector to a specific remote JMS Broker. 
I tried to follow the steps reported on the Decanter documentation, so I installed the jms appender, then I created the JMS connection factory using the jms:create command.
Specifically I created the jms factory with the command:

`jms:create --url tcp://X.Y.Z.W:61616 --username username --password password test`

and I edited the org.apache.karaf.decanter.appender.jms.cfg accordingly

```
#####################################
# Decanter JMS Appender Configuration
#####################################
# Name of the JMS connection factory
connection.factory.name = jms/test

# Name of the destination
destination.name = monitoring-topic

# Type of the destination (queue or topic)
destination.type = topic
password = password
username = username
```

With this configuration I'm not able to see any message on the remote broker, and even any error log messages.

I tried even with a local broker by installing the Activemq features. But still I cannot see any message on the broker side.

What am I missing? Should I install some other Karaf's features?

Thanks

Comment: you did install the jms appender?

Comment: Yes of course, I followed the user guide of Karaf Decanter.